# JavaScript for loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario

First I get the total rows in my html table with JQuery as follows

```
var rowCount = $('#update_menu_items tr').length;
```

and then I get a result back.

Now I want to loop threw values with a for loop that should not exceed the rowcount, but I do not get a result back, since loop does not work. Not sure if I left something out.

Here's the loop

```
var i;

  for (i=0;i<rowCount;i++)

    alert(i);

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an open brace:

```
for (i=0;i<rowCount;i++) { // <- here
    alert(i);
}
```

Comment: :-) true! totally missed it ;-)

Comment: or he has a closing brace where he shouldn't.  Depends which way you look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

another approach of loop

$('tr', '#update_menu_items').each(function(row) { alert($row); });